# emacs AucTeX:Turn off auto-fill-mode inside a particular LaTeX environment

Tags: emacs, auctex

I like using `auto-fill-mode` for hard line wrapping. However, when I'm making a big `tabular` in a `.tex` file, I like using `align-current` to have the table look *somewhat* like it would when printed. The difficulty is that if I have a table that is longer than the line width, `auto-fill-mode` breaks it, and then `align-current` can't put things to rights and gets confused.

Is there a way to tell emacs that when I'm between the `\begin` and `\end` tags of a particular kind of environment (in this case, tabular), don't word wrap...

Comment: Interesting problem which also bugged me a lot. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008849/suppress-emacs-auto-fill-in-a-selected-region. The second code sample by Ivan Andrus works nicely for me.

Comment: Hmmm... actually doesn't seem to work out of the box. It only disabled auto-fill-mode because it gave an error in my .emacs file.

Comment: [The solution the stackoverflow question worked for me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11480465/194894)

Answer (score 1):

There are many things you can do, including but not limited to (In order of implementation time):

- You can turn off auto-fill-mode and use `M-q` ([fill-paragraph](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fill-Commands.html)) to
  manually fill when you need it.
- You can use [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-table-editor.html#Built_002din-table-editor) on-the-fly to create and edit clean tabular data.
- You can [advise](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) fill-paragraph to do something different depending on context